# for iOS dev, how my app might know, for a given file type, which other app could open it

Tags: ios, document, file-type

in iOS devices, the Mail app offers "Open In..." option for attachments. The apps listed have registered their CFBundleDocumentTypes with the OS. What I am wondering is how my app might know, for a given file type, which other app could open it ?

Comment: Why do you need to know which apps can open a file? Is it not sufficient to know that one or more apps can open your file?

Comment: I want to do a filter by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API for this, however, you can open the sheet that Mail.app shows using the `UIDocumentInteractionController` class. It doesn't give you access to the names of the Apps that can handle the document, but its probably better than nothing.